# Is it possible to Install only SQL Server database engine without installing SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-engine

I have a Windows application which uses a database on the server. My connection string is something like:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Server=10.100.10.100;Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security = true");
```

Is there any way I can only install only the SQL Server database engine or any such which should communicate to database on the server, but SQL Server Management Studio should not be installed on the client's machine as data should not be accessible or shown to the end user.

how about installing only SQLEXPR_x64_ENU which is available on miscrosoft website, sizes around 135 mb. Would that help me with  connecting my app to database without studio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can install sql database engine with out client tools anywhere..remeber ssms is only option to connect to server,client can use anything sqlcmd as well

Comment: You can use xampp and access db using both cmd and phpmyadmin.

Comment: @TheGameiswar you meant to say there no way to achieve this without SSMS? how about installing only SQLEXPR_x64_ENU which is available on miscrosoft website, sizes around 135 mb. Would that help me with  connecting my app to database without studio?

Comment: **OF COURSE** you can install just the database engine - absolutely no problem at all. But remember: even if **you** leave away SSMS, the enduser can still install SSMS or some other SQL frontend tool and figure out how to connect to your database. Leaving out SSMS does **NOT** make your databases "safe" or impossible to view with some third-party tools .....

Comment: @marc_s thanks mate, will figure out ways to do it.